# How to collect multiple Q-Q plots into a single figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, qqplot

I have created a total of 6 individual Q-Q plots using Matplotlib, and would now like to collect them all into a singles 3x2 figure. The individual figures have lines drawn on them to show outliers that are +/-2 standard deviations from the Q-Q line.

Individual figures are made as follows, and turn out as expected (see picture):
[These are the individual plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf8f7.png)

```
f = plt.figure(1)
sm.qqplot(x1, line='r', fit=False, loc = np.mean(x1), scale = np.std(x1))
abline(slope1, intercept1 + 2*np.std(x1))
abline(slope1, intercept1 - 2*np.std(x1))
plt.title('STATS250')
f.show()

g = plt.figure(2)
sm.qqplot(x2, line='r', fit=False, loc = np.mean(x2), scale = np.std(x2))
abline(slope2, intercept2 + 2*np.std(x2))
abline(slope2, intercept2 - 2*np.std(x2))
plt.title('DATASCI306')
g.show()

h = plt.figure(3)
sm.qqplot(x3, line='r', fit=False, loc = np.mean(x3), scale = np.std(x3))
abline(slope3, intercept3 + 2*np.std(x3))
abline(slope3, intercept3 - 2*np.std(x3))
plt.title('MATH217')
h.show()
```

I also used this function to plot the lines:

```
    def abline(slope, intercept):
        """Plot a line from slope and intercept"""
        axes = plt.gca()
        x_vals = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
        y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
        plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, '--')
        return
```

I know I should be using some flavor of...

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(9,20))
    ax= axes.flatten()
    for i in range(6):
        sm.qqplot(x[i], line='r', fit=False, loc = np.mean(x[i]), scale = np.std(x[i]), ax=ax[i])
        abline(slope[i], intercept[i] + 2*np.std(x[i]))
        abline(slope[i], intercept[i] - 2*np.std(x[i]))
    
    plt.show()
```

...however I just can't seem to make it all work together; all the lines end up in the last plot. I think the issue is the way I'm adding the lines to the QQ-plots, but not really sure how to proceed. All the lines end up in the last plot. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZITV.png)

UPDATE! I found by tweaking the helper function by passing it the subplot axis handle like so...

```
def abline2(slope, intercept, ax):
    """Plot a line from slope and intercept"""
    axes = ax
    x_vals = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
    y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
    axes.plot(x_vals, y_vals, '--')
    return
```

...and adding the axis to the qqplot call it worked!

```
sm.qqplot(x[i], line='r', fit=False, loc = np.mean(x[i]), scale = np.std(x[i]), ax=ax[i])
```

Comment: Your issue seems to be with `axes = plt.gca()`. Can you also pass `ax[i]` to the `abline` method and plot accordingly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I pass a matplotlib object through a function; as Axis, Axes or Figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739277/how-should-i-pass-a-matplotlib-object-through-a-function-as-axis-axes-or-figur)

Comment: Your recommendation worked; passing the axis to the line function it worked exactly as intended. Grateful for your help!